# How to substitute the values while Fetching itself

Tags: mysql

I have a table as shown

```
 CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `T1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T4` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T5` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   status int default 0 
);

Insert into document (T1 , status ) values ('Pocorn',0);
Insert into document (T1 , T2  , status ) values ('Pocorn', 'Bucket' , 1);
Insert into document (T1 , T2 , T3 , status) values ('Pocorn', 'Chocka' , 'Small' , 2);
```

This is my sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d816e/2

My question is that i  have 3 status as

0  indiccates Pending

1  indicates Approved

2 indicates Declined

Is it possible to substitute the values as Pending , Approved and Declined while fetching

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1, t2, t3, t4, 
case 
  when status=0 then 'Pendig'
  when status=1 then 'Approved'
  when status=2 then 'Declined'
  end
  from document
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when status = 0
            then 'pending'
            when status = 1
            then 'approved'
            when status = 2
            then 'declined'
       end as status
from document
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d816e/4)